# Plot a pie chart when the number of columns within the range varies

Tags: vba, excel

```
Month   Organic Direct
Dec-15  £3,112  £0
```

I recorded VBA code that plots a pie chart for the above data. The data I am exporting can have up to 6 headings (the above example shows two headings). The code is set up to select a range that is 6 columns wide. Charts need to be adjusted manually when less than 6 headings have been exported.

What do I need so the range used fits only the data e.g. when there are only 2 headings rather than 6?

Comment: please include your code...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how much help you need, since you posted no code.

In the simplest case, in Excel 2013 and 2016 you can use

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(251, xlPie).Chart.SetSourceData _
    Source:=ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion, PlotBy:=xlRows
```

In Excel 2007 and 2010 (and 2013 and 2016, but it doesn't have the nicer default style applied):

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart(xlPie).Chart.SetSourceData _
    Source:=ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion, PlotBy:=xlRows
```

This assumes the data starts in cell A1 and the data being plotted does not touch any other data (that is, there is a blank column to the right of the last column of data, and a blank row below the two rows you've shown with labels and data). CurrentRegion finds the data-containing region surrounding the reference range (the reference range in this case is cell A1), up to blank rows and columns.

Answer (score -1):

Does this all take place in the same workbook?

i would start by looking at dynmamic ranges,

Heres a good starting point: 
https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/5-ways-to-create-a-dynamic-auto-adjusting-vba-range

and also look here: 
[Using VBA to select a dynamic range of cells and create a chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25204059/using-vba-to-select-a-dynamic-range-of-cells-and-create-a-chart)